# Impossible Rails Syntax: Order has_many with polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

Statically-typed, compile-time-checked programmer brain, here, struggling with a rails function call.

In a model when we specify `has_many`, we can specify the sort order like this `has_many :requirements, -> { order(created_at: :asc) }, :dependent => :destroy`.

But when we have a polymorphic association such as this
`has_many :text_fields, as: :describable, :dependent => :destroy` how can we add the sorting lambda?

I have tried every possible permutation of syntax except, apparently, the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have clarified that it is the child records (text_fields) that you want ordered. You could use a `default_scope`, like so:

```
class ParentModel < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :text_fields, as: :describable, :dependent => :destroy
end

class TextField < ApplicationRecord
  default_scope { order(created_at: :asc) }
end
```

But think hard before doing so because [default_scope is evil](https://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/2013/06/15/default_scope-is-evil/). Among other things, you can't override an `order` that is defined in a default_scope. I am not familiar with `requirements`, but you may not be able to override the order defined within `requirements` either.

I think you are much better served creating a scope like so:

```
class ParentModel < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :text_fields, as: :describable, :dependent => :destroy
end

class TextField < ApplicationRecord
  scope :default_order, -> { order(created_at: :asc) }
end
```

Then call it explicitly when you want your records ordered that way:

```
TextField.all.default_order
```

or

```
parent_record.text_fields.default_order
```

Comment: But this call `YourModel.all.default_order` is me getting the list of all rows from the `your_models` table, right?  What I need is that when I obtain one YourParent which has_many YourModels, then `theparent.your_models` should be sorted.  This only came up for me when switching from MySQL to Postgres for Heroku.

Comment: Sure, but the concept is the same: `your_parent.child_records.default_order`. A `scope` works on any existing collection of records.

Comment: But wait, to solve my problem, that scope definition needs to go in the `TextField` model from my example, (i.e. the `child` in the relationship), right?

Comment: Hard to say, because you haven't specified the names of your models, but yes, the scope would go on the model that is actually getting ordered.

Comment: @Matthew James Briggs If this answer was helpful, please accept is as correct. Thanks.